# Ranger what program is opening file?

Tags: ranger

I'm using ranger and when I navigate to a folder with audio files and press enter it plays mp3 files in terminal.

The terminal audio program isn't my default as when I double click from GUI a different program opens.

I want to figure out what program Ranger is using so I can try using it manually for wave files, which aren't opening in Ranger.

Any suggestions on finding out what program is being used?

[image]

Comment: you could try `strace` or similar (e.g. `sysdig`) to see what is being exec'd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applications which ranger uses are defined in the rifle.conf.

These are the default settings under Fedora for audio related stuff:

```
#--------------------------------------------
# Audio without X
#-------------------------------------------
mime ^audio|ogg$, terminal, has mplayer  = mplayer -- "$@"
mime ^audio|ogg$, terminal, has mplayer2 = mplayer2 -- "$@"
mime ^audio|ogg$, terminal, has mpv      = mpv -- "$@"
ext midi?,        terminal, has wildmidi = wildmidi -- "$@"

#--------------------------------------------
# Video/Audio with a GUI
#-------------------------------------------
mime ^video|audio, has gmplayer, X, flag f = gmplayer -- "$@"
mime ^video|audio, has smplayer, X, flag f = smplayer "$@"
mime ^video,       has mpv,      X, flag f = mpv -- "$@"
mime ^video,       has mpv,      X, flag f = mpv --fs -- "$@"
mime ^video,       has mplayer2, X, flag f = mplayer2 -- "$@"
mime ^video,       has mplayer2, X, flag f = mplayer2 -fs -- "$@"
mime ^video,       has mplayer,  X, flag f = mplayer -- "$@"
mime ^video,       has mplayer,  X, flag f = mplayer -fs -- "$@"
mime ^video|audio, has vlc,      X, flag f = vlc -- "$@"
mime ^video|audio, has totem,    X, flag f = totem -- "$@"
mime ^video|audio, has totem,    X, flag f = totem --fullscreen -- "$@"
```

Locate your ranger config folder(usually *$HOME/.config/ranger*), open the rifle.conf file and search for those lines.

Comment: I don't have a `rifle.conf` in that folder. The folder does exists and contains these sub-folders: `bookmarks history tagged`

Comment: Look for the file in /usr/share/doc/ranger/config

Comment: so ranger has re-invented `mailcap(5)`?

Comment: Where is `rifle.conf` located? @jsus

Answer (score 1):

After startup, ranger creates a directory ~/.config/ranger. To copy the default configuration to this directory issue the following command:

$ ranger --copy-config=all

```
rc.conf - startup commands and key bindings
commands.py - commands which are launched with :
rifle.conf - applications used when a given type of file is launched.
```